# Get only files modified within last 30 minutes using sftp get

Tags: shell, sftp, expect

Within a `.sh` script, I'm using `expect` to automatically `sftp` to another computer in order to `get` files. My script will be set to run every 30 minutes, at which point I want to `get` *only* files that were created (modified) since the last run (risking repetition, within the last 30 minutes). I know that the files will follow a specific naming method: `AppData*.RAW` where `*` will be a date and time string. However, I do not know when the files will be created or transferred to the computer I am communicating with, nor do I know how many there could be as the number will vary.

```
...
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
spawn sftp user@host
expect "User's password: "
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get ????"
EOD
...
```

I searched for help with `get` and found references to using the `-neweronly` switch, as well as trying `synchronize`. However, I don't know how to implement either of these, or if `synchronize` is even an option in `sftp` dialogue.
[Help with `get`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get)

Also, the computer that I have to `sftp` to stores incoming files in a directory with thousands of older files (from 2013 to present), so it's imperative that I only get files from the last half hour.

Comment: Would `rsync` fit your needs better?

Comment: Do you even know ssh key pair ? Expect is not a good practice

Comment: @jordanm I don't know if `rsync` is something I could use. Do both computers need to have it? I think the other comp is a Windows machine, but the admin hasn't been overly helpful. @Gilles I have tried using the ssh key pair, but it does not work. I cant actually `ssh` to the other machine, only `sftp` via PuTTy or FileZilla.

Comment: @jordanm As a follow up, I tried using `rsync`, but I get "exec request failed on channel 0," which is the same as when I try to just `ssh` to it.

Comment: You referred to documentation for `winscp`. Is that the client you're using, or are you using the sftp from the openssh package?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That was just the documentation I found. I am using PuTTy's `sftp` command. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Putty's sftp client is normally named `psftp`. If you type `sftp --version`, what does it print?

Comment: `[user]$ sftp --version

usage: sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config]
            [-o ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests]
            [-S program] [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host`

Answer (score 2):

`sftp` has limited capabilities. The easiest way to do complex things over SFTP is to use [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). SSHFS is a filesystem that uses SFTP to make a remote filesystem appear as a local filessytem. On the client, SSHFS requires [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which is available on most modern unices. On the server, SSHFS requires SFTP; if the server allows SFTP then you can use SSHFS with it.

For example, to copy the files modified in the past 30 minutes, first mount the remote directory over SFTP with `sshfs`. Use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) if you have to use a password for SSH. Then use the command you'd use locally (here, I use GNU utilities, but depending on what you're doing, `rsync -a mnt/ /local/path/` might be better). Unmount the SSHFS filesystem when you've finished.

```
mkdir mnt
sshpass -f password.txt sshfs user@host: mnt
find mnt -mmin -30 -exec cp -t /local/path/ {} +
fusermount -u mnt
```